# Is there a TeX macro for three-legged pi?

Tags: symbols

One of the stranger symbols to ever cross the pages of a mathematician is the three-legged pi symbol, advocated by Bob Palais in his piece [π is wrong](http://www.math.utah.edu/~palais/pi.pdf) as a symbol for 2π (and as opposed to using the Greek letter tau for that purpose).

Some examples of three-legged pi in action:

[image]

Is there a standard (La)TeX way to get this symbol? I had a look on google, detexify, ctan and symbols-a4, and didn't get anywhere.

(Also: I don't particularly intend to use it, and definitely not in a publication. But it'd be nice to have around.)

Comment: [Wikipedia's Tau proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(geometry)#Tau_proposal) prints this as `\pi\!\;\!\!\!\pi`. Not pretty.

Comment: This rather looks like a handwritten cyrillic `t` (looking as some kind of a handwritten Latin m)

Comment: @Werner: Nice idea, but the kerning is wrong -- I just tried it (at least with standard fonts)

Comment: it is hard to read 3 legged pi, vs. 2*pi. So I think  for readability alone, it is bad idea to use this symbol in actual papers.

Comment: @Nasser I'm glad you agree with the question.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that we've had this question before but I'm unable to find it… maybe I don't remember correctly.

Comment: @clemens: Perhaps not in this context. I remember the symbol being used in Astronomy as well (or a very similar one)

Comment: ouch....I'll add this symbol to the list next to `\xi`,`\zeta`, and `\wp` for *don't bother*.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the idea of Palai's definition, given by Nessiesson's answer - how about this?

`\usepackage{graphicx}`

```
\[
\newcommand{\twopi}{\pi \mskip-6.6mu \reflectbox{$\tau$}}
\twopi
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to Palais' [own website](http://www.math.utah.edu/~palais/pi.html), it seems that the macro
`\def \newpi{{\pi\mskip -7.8 mu \pi}}` was used.

Comment: This looks like a four-legged  pi

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty close, but it's font-dependent. On my system it produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AvxwC.png), which isn't quite there either. (Under `lmodern`.)